# jsTree two_state checkboxes - single nodes within checked parent are also returned on get_checked

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree to display a folder and file hierarchy. I have turned on two-state checkboxes to allow files and directories to be selected independently, to avoid that a directory is automatically selected even if all contained files are checked. This works flawlessly, but I am then having trouble when retrieving the checked elements.

My code looks like this:

```
var checkedInTree = $("#docTree").jstree("get_checked", null, false);
```

If a single file within folder A (which contains several files) is checked, and folder A itself is also checked then I expected that I would only get folder A when calling get_checked with the get_all parameter = false. I gather from the JSTree documentation that if the get_all flag is FALSE, single checked nodes within a checked parent node will not be returned since selecting a parent node automatically includes all subnodes. Now I get both the folder and the file, regardless of the value of get_all.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Is this a bug in jsTree?